# use mysql data and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Id like to make a sort of featured content slider with jQuery and display data from a mySQL table at two seperate events
here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/silcon_sys/8PMUg/65/
now I want to have the data: cover, year, label, artist, title
I made a php script that puts this data nicely into the seperate slides.

on clicking 'info' jQuery animates a slide down animation wich holds the rest of the table data.

how do I make the jQuery drop-down display the data from the row the rest of the data belongs to??

I guess I have to use a control structure of some sort. I can't build the whole thing at once and am having a hard time getting a good awnser to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this isn't straight javascript or jQuery - you need to implement some AJAX callbacks that allow your server to process some data then return the results that you want displayed.

Once you have the data from that callback, you can just set the HTML of the drop-down.

```
var value = 1;
var value2 = 2;

$.post('backgroundScript.php', {
        val: value
        val2: value2
    }, function(data) {
        $('#myElement').html(data);
    }
);
```

Comment: This I can try, AJAX is something I use too little anyway.

Comment: @silcon_system Anytime you need something to update without a page load (and it needs some back-end processing), go with AJAX. It will save you many headaches.